# Separating Web Role and Web Application into separate projects

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

When creating an Azure Web Role with ASP.NET WebAPI, both the Web application code and WebRole.cs file are in the same project.

I like separating them into different projects e.g.

Project.WebApplication  <----- web application that contains no role related references

Project.WebRole <----- contains WebRole.cs file

Question is how do I link them up so that during packaging web application is copied over and deployed?

I thought simply including physicaldirectory attribute with sitename in csdef file would do it but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. You can change the name of the role (default name is Web) and the physicalDirectory that you specify must point to the Web Application's root folder.